# Unable to delete Names in Excel 2013 by VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am currently trying to automate the process of removing unwanted Names from the Name Manager.

```
Sub DeleteNames

Dim myName As name

  For Each myName In ThisWorkbook.Names

       If InStr(myName.RefersTo, "#NAME!") > 0  Or InStr(myName.RefersTo, "=Database!") > 0 Then

                 myName.Delete

                 'MsgBox myName.RefersTo

       End If
```

I am able to correctly get what my check requires, however the name cannot be removed.

Is there anything wrong with my steps?

Comment: is the condition met? in my opinion you need to change condition into something like this: `If InStr(1, myName.RefersTo, "#NAME!") > 0 And ... Then`. The next line `MyName.Delete` is correct one.

Comment: it worked after adding in 1. thank u so much! however, can you explain the rationale. because from my understanding, it is an optional parameter, and if I omit the 1 by default it will start from 1.

Comment: `InStr function` is tricky one, you need to be careful when using it while all parameters could be...optional. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: Thank u for the article and your help @KazimierzJawor